# Unable to delete file with _wremove API (permission issue)

Tags: c++, file

I'm unable to delete a temporary file from my C++ application, it's failing with "permission denied" error. Here's the code snippet,

```
void DeleteTempFile(const std::wstring& path) {
    wchar_t* wc = const_cast<wchar_t*>( path.c_str() );
    if( _wremove( wc ) != 0 )
        Log(fatal, std::string("Error: ") + std::strerror(errno) + std::string(" while deleting file: ") + std::string(path.begin(),path.end()));
    else
        Log(fatal, std::string("Successfully deleted file: ") + std::string(path.begin(),path.end()));
}
```

And this is the log I'm getting when I execute this code, 
*Error: Permission denied while deleting file: C:/Windows/SERVIC~1/LOCALS~1/AppData/Local/Temp/abcD12E.pdf*

Can somebody please help me in resolving this permission issue?

Comment: I don't even have the permission to *look* into that directory. Are you sure the file is created in the first place?

Comment: If you run your application with elevated privileges does it work?

Comment: @BoP Yes, the file exists. I can see the file from the Cygwin terminal in administrative mode.

Comment: @Eljay I'm running this application from Visual Studio and it's running in administrative mode.

Comment: Does it work if you run the application from File Explorer by right-clicking on the EXE and selecting "Run as administrator"?

Comment: @Eljay No, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does anything currently have the file opened?

Comment: @Eljay yes, some data produced by my overall application.

Comment: You can't delete an opened file, you'll get permission denied.  Even with elevated privileges.  (On Windows.  Other operating systems may have different constraints and allowances.)

Comment: uses handle (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) from sysinternals to see if anybody has the file open

Comment: also procmon will show you exactly what is happening to the file

Comment: Try logging the (numeric) value returned by `GetLastError`.  This conveys more information than `errno` and might give you a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/remove-wremove?view=msvc-170):

> **remove, _wremove**
>
> [...]
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Each of these functions returns 0 if the file is successfully deleted. Otherwise, it returns -1 and sets errno either to EACCES to indicate that the path specifies a read-only file, specifies a directory, or **the file is open**, or to ENOENT to indicate that the filename or path was not found.

The call to `_wremove` is returning `EACCES` since *Permission denied* is printed (check [`errno` constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-constants?view=msvc-170)). So there are 3 options:

1. Your file is open (You need to close the file in the first place before calling `_wremove`).
2. Your path is a directory name.
3. The file is read-only (You need to change file permissions).

It cannot be 2 (I'd bet `abcD12E.pdf` is a file). Check whether is 1 or 3 and take the action in brackets.

Comment: To add to that: Based on the fact that it's a pdf-file Option 1 is likely; and since it is in a temporary directory Option 3 seems odd.

Comment: @HansOlsson Yes, indeed. I think it is 1, very reasonable, I just wanted OP to be able to rule the others out himself.